# How do they say "ich" in Bavaria(n)?

Tags: dialect, regional, austrian, bavarian

According to https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f25c/ the majority say "i", but according to https://coerll.utexas.edu/dib/pho.php?k=7 "isch" is Bavarian for "ich". Who's right?

Comment: "i" is correct. The utexas-link contains a lot of mistakes in its Bavarian-section.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Atlas der Deutschen Altagssprache is right. The most common form for "ich" is "i" in Bavaria.

Nobody from Bavaria says “isch” for “ich”. The rule

> ch is pronounced sch

does not apply to Bavarian dialects but may apply to Rhineland dialects.

Also the rule

> diminutive endings -chen and -lein are pronounced -le (singular) and -la (plural)

describes the Swabian dialect and

> final n dropped at the end of words

is typical of Alemannic dialects (Switzerland, very west of Austria) and Hessian, although the actual articulation is quite different between these two dialects.

It thus seems to me that the author of this website simply subsumed southern dialects as "Bavarian".

On a side note, it's also questionable to give dialects as pronunciation rules for standard German words. Dialects feature their own morphology that is much more complex than just pronouncing some syllables differently.

Comment: Doch, Rheinländer sagen allüberall "isch", auch in Bayern. Isch zum Beispiel, als isch dort lebte (in Münschen). :)

Comment: Diminutive can, however, be changed to _-el_ or _-erl_, but that's more common in Austria, I think.

Comment: "-la" is also used in Franconian, as far as I remember.

Comment: @userunknown Musste gerade sehr lachen. Habe die Antwort entsprechend bearbeitet :)

Comment: In addition to the problems listed in this answer, the utexas page seems to think that "gelegen" is a form of "legen" instead of "liegen"

Comment: So, is the use of `i` due to the "cutting off" of the `ch`, as opposed to being influenced by the English "I"? That's how I understand it.

Comment: @BruceWayne Note sure what you're saying. It's certainly not English influence but English and Bavarian might share the same root for "i/I". Also, as I said in the answer, it doesn't make sense to think of dialects in derivation rules ("cutting off") from standard language. Dialects feature distinct grammar and vocabulary. Rather, simply speaking, standard German evolved from a some specific dialects (which Martin Luther chose to base his bible translation on).

Comment: @BruceWayne I was wondering about that also. It's my understanding that "i" evolved from "ik/ih" separately on the Continent and in Britain. Apparently, languages have a habit of dropping the trailing "k/h". Also, I checked Old English dictionaries online, and they translate "i" as "ic". This is presumably based on old texts, and not linguists just assuming that it was like Frisian/Dutch. But I didn't read those texts myself, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: @BruceWayne As a middle possibility, perhaps *some* German people that came to Britain might have been using "i" already (a minority of the "Anglo-Saxons"). But, over time, this way of saying "I" became fashionable and took over. I guess we cannot know.

Comment: I think the author of the site chose “ich” as an example without thinking if the result was actually Bavarian. Even if describing a dialect as a transformation of another is inadequate for a serious student, it seems a reasonable way of giving a beginner a feeling for the dialect.

Answer (score 1):

In Bavaria and in the region where Bavarian is spoken the preferred way of native people to speak the personal pronoun *»ich«* is *»i«.* So, in this specific case it makes no difference if you are asking for *Bavaria* or for *Bavarian.* But in other cases there might be a difference. (For details about how Bavaria and Bavarian differ, see below.)

Worth to mention is also, that in big cities (Vienna with 1.9 million residents and Munich with 1.5 million residents but also Nürnberg, Augsburg, Graz, Linz) the number of dialect speakers is significant lower than in rural regions. So, you will find a large number of people saying *»ich«* in these cities. And of course there are also people from other regions living in Bavaria and in regions where Bavarian is spoken who speak other dialects, and among them there are people who use to say *»isch«.*

---

The rest is not a direct answer to your question, but still something you should know:

Asking for *Bavaria* or for *Bavarian* can make a big difference (think of *England* and *English*):

- **Bavaria**
  This one of the 16 states of the Federal Republic of Germany
  Dialects spoken in Bavaria are:

  - East Franconian
    in northern parts of Bavaria (Würzburg, Bamberg, Bayreuth, Nürnberg, etc.)
  - North Bavarian
    in most parts of Oberpfalz (Neumarkt in der Oberpfalz, Amberg, Schwandorf)
  - Middle Bavarian
    East of Augsburg and south of Regensburg, including that capital city of Bavaria, Munich
  - Swabian
    West of Augsburg (Lindau, Kempten, Neu-Ulm)

  Note that East Franconian and Swabian are **not** Bavarian dialects, although they are spoken in Bavaria (and in other German states)
- **Bavarian**
  This is a group of dialects spoken in parts of Bavaria and in 8 of the 9 states of the Federal Republic of Austria and even in a northern region of Italy. It consits of:

  - North Bavarian
    Spoken only in the region mentioned above
  - Middle Bavarian
    Also called *Danube Bavarian*
    Spoken in that parts of Bavaria described above, but also in these six Austrian states (German names in brackets):

    - Salzburg (Salzburg)
    - Upper Austria (Oberösterreich)
    - Lower Austria (Niederösterreich)
    - Vienna (Wien)
    - Burgenland (Burgenland)
    - Styria (Steiermark)
  - South Bavarian
    Also called *Alpine Bavarian*
    Spoken in South Tyrol, which is a region in Italy, next to the Austrian border and in these Austrian states:

    - Tyrol (Tirol)
    - Carinthia (Kärnten)

  Note that there is a ninth Austrian state, Vorarlberg, where people don't speak a Bavarian dialect but an Alemannic dialect.

---

Comment: The OP is aware of the difference. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71104/at-what-age-do-the-speakers-of-bavarian-learn-standard-german